# sharepoint data entry validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation-list-items

I want my data entry to not be on a list of exempted entries.
I want to use a list of entries. But am open to suggestion 
Tested in excel by placing exceptions in a column. Extracted to sharepoint a small table to create a library of entries

error message I enter reads "This Job Code is exempt from this process"

in sharepoint validation i enter this formula...
`IF([Job Code]=[Exceptions],"true","False")` which isnt what i want however;

[exceptions] after i save the formula converts to this..

```
IF([Job Code]=Exceptions,"true","False")
```

this didnt work correctly so i reversed the outcomes 
`IF([Job Code]=[exceptions],"False","True")` which is the result i want, if the number exists in the exceptions collumn i dont want them to be able to save!

In excel i used this formula...

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A9,Table1[Exceptions],0))
```

this does exactly what i want...but i want this to happen in sharepoint and not validate the entry...

[image: excel snip]
[image: excel snip2]

i have tried other formulas with no luck, i keep getting a syntax error when saving... examples are...

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:F2=A3)),TRUE,FALSE)` this works but i dont know how to convert the single cell and range/array into sharepoint 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately,** the `Validation Setting` formula is only applied to [specific fields](http://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint) on the same **ROW**.

> Check [The Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated
>   Column Formula](http://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint)

Therefore, you **can't** search for **column values** and validate against these values in the SharePoint validation setting or calculated field like Excel formula!

Answer (score 0):

We need using some code to achieve it. The following code for your reference, add the code into script editor web part into new/edit form page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction() { 
    var jobCode = $("input[title='Job Code']").val();

    if(isJobCodeExempt(jobCode)){
        $("input[title='Job Code']").after('<br/><span class="ms-formvalidation ms-csrformvalidation" id="Error_JobCode"><span role="alert">This Job Code is exempt from this process.<br></span></span>'); 
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}
function isJobCodeExempt(jobCode){
    var flag=false;
    var listID=_spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace("{","").replace("}","");
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'"+listID+"')/items?$filter=Exceptions eq "+jobCode,
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){                 
                flag=true;
            }

        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to achieve this by putting conditions and rules on my submit button. rule 1 query using a data connection, rule 2 2 conditions JobCodeEntry is not blank, and jbocode entry does not match column 2 = specific output.... rule 3 same as 2 but entry does match, performs different output  solved!